# Upload especific files to a ftp directory using python

Tags: python, ftp

I need to upload some files into different directories on ftp server. The files are named like this:

- Broad_20140304.zip.
- External_20140304.zip.
- Report_20140304.

They must be placed into the next directories:

- Broad.
- External.
- Report.

I want something like: for filename like External put it into External directory.
I have the next code, but this put all zip files into the "Broad" Directory. I want just the broad.zip file into this directory, not all of them.

```
def upload_file():
    route = '/root/hb/zip'  
    files=os.listdir(route)
    targetList1 = [fileName for fileName in files if fnmatch.fnmatch(fileName,'*.zip')]
    print 'zip files on target list:' , targetList1
    try:
        s = ftplib.FTP(ftp_server, ftp_user, ftp_pass)
        s.cwd('One/Two/Broad')
        try:
            print "Uploading zip files"
            for record in targetList1:
                file_name= ruta +'/'+ record
                print 'uploading file: ' + record
                f = open(file_name, 'rb')
                s.storbinary('STOR ' + record, f)
                f.close()
            s.quit()
        except:
            print "file not here " + record
    except:
        print "unable to connect ftp server"
```

Answer (score 0):

The function has hard coded value for `s.cwd` so it is putting all files in one dir. You can try something like below to get the remote directory dynamically from file name.

Example: (*Not Tested*)

```
def upload_file():
    route = '/root/hb/zip'  
    files=os.listdir(route)
    targetList1 = [fileName for fileName in files if fnmatch.fnmatch(fileName,'*.zip')]
    print 'zip files on target list:' , targetList1
    try:
        s = ftplib.FTP(ftp_server, ftp_user, ftp_pass)
        #s.cwd('One/Two/Broad')  ##Commented Hard-Coded
        try:
            print "Uploading zip files"
            for record in targetList1:
                file_name= ruta +'/'+ record
                rdir = record.split('_')[0]  ##get the remote dir from filename
                s.cwd('One/Two/' + rdir)     ##point cwd to the rdir in last step
                print 'uploading file: ' + record
                f = open(file_name, 'rb')
                s.storbinary('STOR ' + record, f)
                f.close()
            s.quit()
        except:
            print "file not here " + record
    except:
        print "unable to connect ftp server"
```